# Sql query to Select one result per all matches

Tags: mysql, sql

I got two tables

Table 1:

```
id|value
1|Tom
1|Lucy
2|Tom
2|Lucy
3|Tom
3|Lucy
3|Bard
```

Table 2:

```
id|value
1|Tom
1|Lucy
2|Tom
2|wrong
3|Tom
3|Lucy
```

Results should be id where all the values match in both tables:

```
1
```

Tried this:

```
select distinct a.id 
from table1 a 
join table2 b on a.id=b.id and a.value=b.value
```

results  are

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Have a look at the `GROUP BY` clause. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx/

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Note that an example is generally more useful when it also shows what's excluded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INTERSECT` comes to mind. Or a `FULL OUTER JOIN` maybe. MySQL supports neither.

The easiest way I can think of in MySQL:

```
select id
from table1
group by id
having (id, group_concat(value order by value)) in
(
  select id, group_concat(value order by value)
  from table2
  group by id
);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=768cc8fb2d01c2b5219a4d56d127d117